# Web service once deployed needs a dependency not used in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, iis-7, reference

I have a web service that once deployed mysteriously needs other DLLs to work.

I have a website running in **C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebsite** and the web service running in **C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebsite\WebService**

I created an application (WebService, pointing to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebsite\WebService) in IIS under the website MyWebsite

When running one of WebService's .svc, I get:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Blah.Web' or one of its dependencies. The system     cannot find the file specified. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web    request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it    originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly   'Blah.Web' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Blah.web is a DLL used for MyWebsite. Why do suddenly my WebService needs this DLL that's not even referenced in VS 2010 ?

Is it a web.config thing ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It's because your web service is nested within your website, so when your website automatically compiles, it's compiling the code in your main website AND the web service website.  However, since the compiler is functioning undert he context of the main website, it's looking in mywebsite\bin for the code instead of \mywebsite\myservice\bin.

Personally, I'd change the architecture and have the web services site separate, and not nested. it should be, at a minimum, its own web Applicaiton (as configured in IIS) or a separate web site.

Comment: OK. Is there any way I could have still http://website/webservice even if Webservice's physical directory is not in Website's physical directory ?

Comment: Do you have IIS configured so that website\webservice is an application? If not or you're not sure, try this Bing search, and use the result appropriate to the version of IIS you're using and check/set it up. http://www.bing.com/search?q=configuring+applications+in+iis&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=configuring+applications+in+iis&sc=1-31&sp=-1&sk=

Comment: Or, if you want the absolute simplest solution, simply copy the .dll into website\bin

Comment: I moved the physical directory WebService out of WebSite's physical dir. and created an application pointing to WebService's new physical directory under WebSite in IIS and still getting the error.

I need it to be accessible under WebSite.

I don't want to copy the DLLs because there's alot of them and said DLLs eventually whine about not finding .xml files too.

Comment: Then I'd just put the .dll in website\bin

Comment: By the way, I just answered another question that gives a farily simple overview of the relationship between the Visual Studio website/web app and the IIS web app.  I think it might be helpful to you.  The key is where the \bin\dll is in relation to the IIS web application.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334235/does-resolve-to-the-root-of-the-current-folder-or-the-root-of-the-website