# What does "~/" resolve to in ASP: the current folder or the root of the website?

Tags: asp.net

does using ~/ in a file path resolve to the root of the current folder or the website?

I have a file structure as such:

```
\
->Folder
-->Page1.Aspx

->App_Themes
-->Theme1
--->Images
--->StyleSheet.css

->Includes
-->Footer.htm

Default.aspx
Default.master
```

I am using my default.master page for Page1.aspx and default.aspx. The master page uses `<!-- #include file="includes/Footer.htm" -->` . Then in my Footer.html i use paths for images such as : ~/App_Themes/Theme1/Images/Image1.png".

The image will display properly in default.aspx but will not be found in Page1.aspx. I thought ~/ meant root of the website when used in a file path?

EDIT:

I was wrong, it is also not working in defaut.aspx. The path that was working is: /App_Themes/Theme1/Images/Image1.png.

Comment: I would recommend against using server-side includes. That's old ASP trash, and shouldn't be used in ASP.NET.

Comment: What should be used instead? custom ascx controls?

Comment: ASCX controls, Master Pages... ANYTHING is better than using includes.  Master Pages is the standard .NET way for content shared across all pages. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx  ASXC controls is the way for including bits within the content of your page.

Comment: Sounds good, I never knew #includes were so bad. I just figured that since i was only #including html segments into my master page it would not matter. Thanks, I will switch my #includes to ASCX controls.

Comment: @Mausimo: as has been said, use UserControls (ASCX) and/or master pages. Most sites even turn off SSI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It resolves to the root of the current web application, which may or may not be the root of the website as a whole.

To understand the difference, see [this article](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/150/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis/).

As a general rule, when you're creating a "website" or a "web application" in Visual Studio, you're actually creating a "Web Application" in IIS speak.

To further muddy the waters, Conceptually, the root of the website is an IIS "application" in and of itself, so you can publish your Visual Studio website/web application to the root of your website.  In that case, ~/ will refer to the root of the site.

If, however, you've got multiple Applications all running in one Site, then in each one the ~/ will refer to the root of that application.

For example, say MySite.com has different applications

- mySite.Com - Distinct app in Visual Studio, has general site content.
- mySite.Com/shop has a shopping cart.  This is a distinct app in Visual Studio, and a distinct IIS application.
- MySite.Com/Support contains a separate, distinct application for customer support.  Ticket submission, chat with a live operator, etc.

In all of the above, mysite.com is the website. but the /* denotes the application.  The ~/ will refer to

- mySite.Com/
- mySite.Com/shop/

and

- MySite.Com/Support/

respectively

Comment: Thanks for the link and answer. It has helped a lot!